# How to change the Model-URL e.g. /comment into a nested URL like /posts/38/comment in Ember Data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've a simple app that has **posts** and **comments**.

If I create a new *comment* within a *post* and save it: Ember's default behaviour is to post the new *Comment* as JSON to "**/comment**".

I like to have it posted to "**/posts/38/comment**" and thought about I overwriting the buildURL-method of a Model-Specific RESTadapter to change the URL.

But the buildURL methods signature is only (type, id). Type is just a string of the model name an id undefined for a new comment.

So how can I access the "to be saved" model's content? Or is there another poper way to get the post-id to build the URL? In this example - How to get access to the number 38 within buildURL.

Or am I on the wrong path and there is a better way to archive it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an `App.Comment`-specific adapter, and customise the `createRecord` method there:

```
App.CommentAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  createRecord: function(store, type, record) {
    var data = {};
    var serializer = store.serializerFor(type.typeKey);

    serializer.serializeIntoHash(data, type, record, { includeId: true });

    // Custom stuff
    var postId = record.get('post.id');
    var url = this.buildURL(type.typeKey, postId) + '/comment';
    return this.ajax(url, "POST", { data: data });
  }
});
```